# How to close a list of OutputStream in Java?

Tags: java, outputstream, try-with-resources

I have a list of `OutputStream` to deal with, and I know when I only need one, I can make sure it is closed using `try-with-resources` pattern, like:

```
try(OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    do something...
} catch (IOException e) {
    do something...
}
```

But what if there is a list of them? Can I just put the list(`ArrayList` or normal array) in the parentheses after `try`?

Comment: There's no explicit support for `List` in try-with-resource statements. If you really want to use `try (...) { ... }` syntax, you'll have to roll your own `AutoCloseable` that wraps a list of `AutoCloseables`. Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/8MtLFLu2) could work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `foreach` (or the standard `for`) for this purpose.

```
OutputStream[] streams = {...};

for (OutputStream stream : streams) {
    try (OutputStream os = stream) {} 
    catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

You cannot *"put `ArrayList` or normal array in the parentheses after `try`"*, because it can work only with objects which implement the interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

Comment: Depending on the use case perhaps doing somehting when the close fails